# octave nmf_bpas error: vertical dimensions mismatch (8x1 vs 1x400)

Tags: octave, nmf

I have a problem with non-negative matrix factorization in octave. I try to estimate synergies from Emg-data, but octave only lets me do this for two or more synergies, but not for one. I was able to reproduce the problem with the following code.
nmf_bpas is from the linear-algebra pkg from octave-forge.

```
V=rand(4, 20);
k=1; k2=2;
[W, H, Iter, HIS]=nmf_bpas(V,k);
```

with this input I get the following error:

```
error: vertical dimensions mismatch (4x1 vs 1x20)
error: called from
    nmf_bpas>getStopCriterion at line 373 column 19
    nmf_bpas at line 266 column 26
```

when I define k>1 as in the following it works

```
[W2, H2, Iter2, HIS2]=nmf_bpas(V,k2);
```

with this input, it works fine, and the output matrices are W2 (4x2) and H2 (2x20).

same problem is when I try it with other codes for nnmf and specify the input data Winit and Hinit for matrices (4x1) and (1x20) (eg.:[W, H] = nmf_pg (V, Winit, Hinit, tol, timelimit, maxiter))

in matlab it works with the nnmf function.

I would be glad about help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `nmf_bpas`.

From what I can tell, the bug is on line 373. Change

```
pGrad = [gradW(gradW<0|W>0); gradH(gradH<0|H>0)];
```

to

```
pGrad = [gradW(gradW<0|W>0); gradH(gradH<0|H>0)(:)];
```

and it will work.

Comment: Reported as [Bug #60650](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60650) on the octave bug tracker.

Comment: I also had to change  line 379 in the same pattern, but now it works fine. thanks